# how do I compute this summation of the expected value

Tags: summation

How do I compute the summation at the end:

$$E(x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x.P(X=x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{x-1}$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Sum_to_infinite_terms

Comment: Many methods [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn).

Comment: Sorry, rewriting my comment. Assuming $P(X=x)$ is a probability function, it can't be the case that $P(X=x)=\left(\frac 56\right)^{x-1}$ since then $P(X=1)=1$ and $P(X=2)=5/6$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the geometric series:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} a^x = \dfrac1{1-a}$$
Differentiate the above with respect to $a$ on both sides to get
$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} xa^{x-1} = \dfrac1{(1-a)^2}$$
Now plug in $a=\dfrac56$ to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been trying geometric method but haven't thought of differentiating.